# Searching for a particular element in a stack

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, stack

I am interested in porting [this Python code](http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2011/11/15/bfs-vs-dfs-graph-search-algorithms-in-python/) to C++. As part of the port, I am using `std::stack` from the `<stack>` header. How can I determine whether some character is contained within a `stack<char>`? For example:

```
std::stack<char> myStack

if (!('y' is included in myStack)) // I know that this is wrong
{
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you use stack and not set?

Comment: There is no way to iterate/find into an `std::stack`, you're only allowed to view the last item pushed and pop it out. You probably want another container.

Comment: If you want to look at all the elements, you probably didn't want a stack.

Comment: In C++, a stack is simply a thin wrapper around a sequential access container(`std::deque` by default) that purposely restricts access to all elements except the top.  You want to remove that restriction, so just use a sequential access container (vector, deque or list).

Answer (score 12):

The C++ `stack` does not support random access, so there is no direct way using a `stack` to check if an element is contained.  You can, however, make a copy of the stack and then continuously `pop` off that stack until the element is found.

Alternatively, if you do need to search the `stack`, you could consider instead using a `deque`, which does support random access.  For example, you could use the `find` algorithm on a `deque` to search for an element:

```
std::find(myDeque.begin(), myDeque.end(), myValue);
```

If you need to frequently search of the `stack`, consider keeping a parallel `std::set` along with the `stack` that stores the same elements as the `stack`.  This way, you can just use `set::find` to check (efficiently) whether the element exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I write `else if (!(std::find(myStack.begin(), myStack.end(), x)))` and gives me error _no operator "!" matches this operants_. Is there any find function that gives back bool or makes this happen?

Comment: The find function returns an iterator rather than a Boolean.  You'd write if (std::find(myStack.begin(), myStack.end(), x) != myStack.end()) { ... }

Answer (score 4):

If you need to find an element in your container, by definition `stack` is the wrong container for your needs. With the extremely minimal amount of information you've provided either `vector` or `deque` sound like they would provide the interface you need (`std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), item);`).

Comment: I used `else if (!(find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), x)))` and `else if (!(find_if(visited.begin(), visited.end(), x)))` it gave me error _no operator "!" matches this operants_.  **How can I return true if the item is found ?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to implement DFS and BFS, using `std::stack` (for DFS) and `std::queue` (for BFS) is indeed appropriate to keep not yet visited nodes, and you only need to use `push()` and `pop()` methods of these containers.

But stack and queue are not sufficient to keep visited nodes. My preference would be to use an associative container, e.g. `std::set`, better yet `unordered_set` if your C++ compiler has it, because searching an arbitrary value in an associative container is faster than in a sequence like `vector` or `deque` (unless data are sorted there).

Comment: Does the `std::set` has a `pop` and `push` function? I searched and found out that there is none functions like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: For the associative containers, the corresponding operations are `erase` and `insert`. And you most likely will not need `erase` because the container would be used for visited nodes. So the program would employ both a stack/queue for the nodes to visit and a set for already visited nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search in the stack frequently, consider using a set alongside. Always keep the set updated too: if any element is popped from stack, erase it from the set , and on any push operation onto the stack, insert into the set too.

```
stack<int> st; 
set<int> s;  


//push 
st.push(2);s.insert(2);

//pop
s.erase(st.top()); st.pop();

//find (what your main objective was)
bool ispresent = s.find(2)!=s.end() ; // on failure the iterator = s.end()
```