# Finding element in stl stack cpp

Tags: c++, search, stl, stack

I need to find an element in stack, so i figure out that i must pop element until i find this element or the stack is empty. In the other words, NOT poping when element is found OR stack is empty. What is wrong with my way of thinking?

```
while (!(stack.top()==searched || stack.empty()))
{
    tmp.push(stack.top());
    stack.pop();
}
```

Code return core dumped if stack doesnt countain searched element, but if stack.top()==searched always return 0, and stack.empty return 1, 1 OR 0 is still 1; !1=0 and 'while' should stop.
Is thera any way to do that? I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Reverse the order of the expressions in your while-condition. You shouldn't be invoking `stack.top()` on an empty stack, but you don't know its empty until the second expression is checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for a particular element in a stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918762/searching-for-a-particular-element-in-a-stack)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Any ideas how to avoid problem with looking at empty stack?

Comment: If you look at my link, you will see that the proposed answer (`std::find` on a deque) is exactly what you need. If your stack is empty, `deque::begin` and `deque::end` will be identical, so `std::find` will return `deque::end` just as in any other case where the element is not found.

Comment: imo if you need to find an item in a stack, you shouldn't be using a stack. Use a `vector` and just treat it like a stack, then you can use `std::find`

Comment: but i need to use stack. and i cant use #include <algorithm>.
it's a taks for my classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is relying on [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages). However, the way it works is that

```
cond_a || cond_b
```

first evaluates `cond_a`, only then `cond_b` *in case this is needed*. In this case, then, your code will only check whether the stack is empty *after* it checked the `top`, which is obviously a mistake. You should reverse the order of your two internal conditions.

Comment: Many thanks, but let's not get carried away :-) Good luck!